# How can I automate after the I entred my credentials in the login page after it redirected me to a different URL?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, css-selectors, selenium-chromedriver

So I wanted to create a simple program that when executed, opens a chrome website, goes to my router's settings page, and modify the speed of the internet as I request from the program.
This is my code in Python 3.9 and I am using the Selenium library.

```
    import time

from selenium import *
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains

usr = "admin"
psr = "Administrator"

url = "http://192.168.1.1/html/content1.asp"
url2 = "http://192.168.1.1/html/content1.asp"


s = Service("D:\chromedriver.exe")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s)


driver.get(url)
driver.find_element(by=By.NAME, value="Username").send_keys(usr)
# driver.find_element_by_name("Username").send_keys(usr)
driver.find_element(by=By.NAME, value="Password").send_keys(psr)
# driver.find_element_by_name("Password").send_keys(psr)
driver.find_element(by=By.ID, value="btnLogin").click()
# driver.find_element_by_id("btnLogin").click()
driver.find_element(by=By.CSS_SELECTOR, value="#link_Admin_1").click()
```

It successfully logs into the router, redirects to the next site, but fails to do anything beyond this line:

```
driver.find_element(by=By.CSS_SELECTOR, value="#link_Admin_1").click()
```

It keeps giving me: selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"#link_Admin_1"}

More information: The website's address is 192.168.1.1, after login, it's 192.168.1.1/html/content1.asp

I am a complete newbie to Selenium, but I am okay with python.
[The login part is successful.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ic7i2.png)
[However, No matter the method I try to find the element, either by ID, CSS_SELECTOR, CLASS_NAME](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NnR6R.png)

Edit: More elaboration: 1- For the second page, I noticed that none of the frames that the page contained appear on the page source(https://pastebin.com/rvj84eCY).
2- So I can only see the frame and its elements using chrome's Inspect...

Comment: Try to replace last two lines of code with following: https://pastebin.com/MnRgrJxe . If it works - then I'll add the answer here. And don't forget to apply import (first line of my code).

Comment: Unfortunately, it times out and gives me this:
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException
It seems that the redirection does something wrong and makes all elements inaccessible.

Comment: Open the website in incognito window manually by url `http://192.168.1.1`. It will redirect you to login page like  `http://192.168.1.1/login-or-something-like-that`. And paste this login url to the `url` variable of your code, this should avoid redirection. And run code one more time (with `WebDriverWait` again).

Comment: I did that already also as a method of redicrection avoidment  but it didn't work.
url = "http://192.168.1.1/html/content1.asp"
url2 = "http://192.168.1.1/html/content1.asp"

Comment: could you please do following: https://pastebin.com/Zx3a3KBV. And then share (via pastebin or any other similar website) content of these 2 .html files created.

Comment: Step through your code in your debugger, and wait a bit before executing your failing line. This is to see if your script is running too fast for your browser, which is a very common problem in Selenium scripts. Redirection generally works fine in Selenium scripts, not inherently a problem.

Comment: This is the first .HTML:
https://pastebin.com/tU0KYSMr
The second:
https://pastebin.com/rvj84eCY

Comment: I tried to wait for a while but the router page gives a maximum time of 5 minutes before it redirects back to the login page.
And 5 minutes or less is a ridiculous time to wait for an element to appear...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The page you are trying to automate contains frames. Selenium is not capable to easily traverse through the frames as each frame is the full-fledged HTML document. But Selenium has tools to [switch to current frame and switch back](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/browser/frames/)

Comment: Thank you so much it actually worked!
The documentation was very useful, but still, it took me a while to realize that I need to use implicit wait to give the frame some time to appear.
2 seconds were enough!